# R and as.numeric()

Tags: r

so we have a0:

```
>a0[1,1:2]
l11      l12
-0.921 0.389593
```

Then;

```
> is.numeric(a0[1,1:2])
[1] FALSE
```

Ok, the text file containing them is a bit of a mess. Then:

```
> as.numeric(a0[1,1:2])
[1] 131   3
```

I *know* there was a trick to solve that. I just can't remember what it was...

EDIT: sample file:

```
 -0.921      0.389593    0.99998742210431    -0.00501553917135373    0.999984216926007   -0.00561835375178836   1   2.36    10  2   0.05    1   1
 0.923842    0.382812    0.999998286086073   -0.00185143860707771    0.999999995689246   9.28520798418186e-05   0   2.03    10  2   0.05    2   1
     -0.82904    0.559261    0.905909593351804   -0.423471142668741      0.899659482046882   -0.436592277031025     1   1.51    10  2   0.05    3   1
 -0.796621   0.604487    0.852012998984401   -0.523520629547306      0.882445298428051   -0.470415024507325     0   2.53    10  2   0.05    4   1
 0.836046    0.54875     0.9211906384523     0.389111561930306   0.926385125966013   0.376577479928014  1   2.66    10  2   0.05    5   1
 -0.873104   -0.487579   0.942147732871282   0.335197925777448   0.957896161639222   0.287114861191206  0   2.5 10  2   0.05    6   1
 -0.728606   0.684948    0.838364634070403   -0.545109842453794      0.770224459340949   -0.637772908042465     1   3.97    10  2   0.05    7   1
 0.759379    -0.650765   0.842087096982091   -0.539341562552223      0.765143566165036   -0.643859707666391     0   1.13    10  2   0.05    8   1
 -0.497911   -0.867269   0.480229829449393   0.877142697003747   0.225403470821452   0.974265505569012  1   0.62    10  2   0.05    9   1
 0.465581    0.885042    0.173457702239973   0.98484131997679    0.159038890626454   0.987272318698497  0   0.79    10  2   0.05    10  1
 -0.772559   -0.634978   0.866527018491628   0.499130169619119   0.859460127819      0.511202786269155  1   19.53   10  2   0.05    11  1
 0.81446     0.580278    0.943553667636478   0.331219679804432   0.895967382559323   0.444119859260758  0   1.73    10  2   0.05    12  1
 -0.792377   0.610095    0.865518659616982   -0.500876681284748      0.877697131009408   -0.479215761654241     1   1.24    10  2   0.05    13  1
 0.844213    -0.536081   0.899692596172177   -0.436524034152723      0.906010964105467   -0.423254217841573     0   2.02    10  2   0.05    14  1
 0.421542    0.906835    0.103422987236111   0.99463746446188    0.102255903720432   0.994758126458044  1   0.47    10  2   0.05    15  1
 0.409305    0.912408    0.0729480114866381      0.997335744681873   0.0838704194992194      0.996476669437386  0   0.45    10  2   0.05    16  1
 -0.664573   -0.747275   0.58764731149828    0.809117196263214   0.603464234608522   0.797390066120936  1   0.85    10  2   0.05    17  1
 0.599777    0.800191    0.524086235602366   0.851665202795172   0.567148160033905   0.823615786984536  0   1.32    10  2   0.05    18  1
 -0.397025   -0.917846   0.030139624142486   0.999545698333273   0.0311215453692834      0.999515607388813  1   0.46    10  2   0.05    19  1
 -0.393222   -0.919468   0.0278258557873373      0.999612785907474   0.0265821201726647      0.999646633009448  0   0.42    10  2   0.05    20  1
 0.772559    0.634978    0.924006045897534   0.38237785911949    0.908075241643739   0.418807062397072  1   8.12    20  2   0.05    1   2
 -0.807518   -0.589907   0.947419893700908   0.319993039017663   0.96499482496042    0.262268922672146  0   5.8 20  2   0.05    2   2
 V1      V2      V3      V4      V5      V6     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 -0.526762   0.850092    -0.311928648717808      0.95010552998553    -0.316412744506619      0.94862161851488   0   3.25    20  2   0.05    4   2
 -0.5161     -0.856543   0.309033921455991   0.951051016186583   0.248027721702134   0.96875293510123   1   1.82    20  2   0.05    5   2
 0.491867    0.870721    0.268019541588267   0.96341347578639    0.167808915882198   0.98581954116889   0   2.69    20  2   0.05    6   2
 0.58991     0.807579    0.51533762936385    0.856987238972464   0.421665311535527   0.906751545379244  1   1.91    20  2   0.05    7   2
 -0.549902   -0.835295   0.442022781946357   0.897003823983155   0.390584116545383   0.920567242466547  0   2.06    20  2   0.05    8   2
 0.800218    -0.599709   0.852476180705526   -0.522766067500292      0.833708092721497   -0.552205411174757     1   47.26   20  2   0.05    9   2
 0.837387    -0.546652   0.910736035285173   -0.41298895146607   0.863018073213623   -0.505173044912974     0   5.36    20  2   0.05    10  2
 0.46345     0.886149    0.179828914086857   0.98369790162343    0.176294786076906   0.984337415931193  1   1.84    20  2   0.05    11  2
 V1      V2      V3      V4      V5      V6     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
     0.759379    0.650765    0.817799312011448   0.575503505874294   0.824911507994246   0.565261889727814  1   7.7 20  2   0.05    13  2
 0.793956    0.608013    0.822124323319108   0.56930799836916    0.812590005961236   0.582835724893317  0   3.8 20  2   0.05    14  2
 0.706746    0.707516    0.70298536741427    0.711204311855196   0.695840302062382   0.718196542755348  1   5.1 20  2   0.05    15  2
 0.663932    0.747827    0.717210127099939   0.696856967809958   0.711000892677057   0.70319110532801   0   4.17    20  2   0.05    16  2
 0.813568    -0.581494   0.904931790793546   -0.425556640191628      0.912655929947496   -0.408728704071137     1   4.24    20  2   0.05    17  2
 -0.836046   0.54875     0.924852673074549   -0.380325561995065      0.92915112499605    -0.369700131077304     0   3.78    20  2   0.05    18  2
 V1      V2      V3      V4      V5      V6     NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
 0.586824    -0.809738   -0.610122851736008      0.792306825535108   -0.588615757355873      0.80841294533943   0   3.07    20  2   0.05    20  2
```

Comment: What is the question exactly? You want (-0.921,0.389593) as a numeric vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have read the numbers as factors; if you use `read.table`, try `header=T` or restructure the data before read. Some sample of the file should be helpful to resolve it.

Workaround would be to first convert factors to strings using `as.character` and then back to numbers with `as.numeric`.

Edit: Code working for provided example:

```
readLines('<filename>')->z
read.table(textConnection(z[-grep('V',z)]))
```

Comment: @mbq Or use the `colClasses` argument in `read.table()`?

Comment: @chl Possibly; depends on how this data look.

Comment: "This is because you have read the numbers as factors; if you use read.table, try header=T or restructure the data before read. Some sample of the file should be helpful to resolve it." nop. "Workaround would be to first convert factors to strings using as.character and then back to numbers with as.numeric." nop. same result.

Comment: @kwak -- remove those "V1 V2..." from the file before doing anything. as.numeric won't work having unconvertable elements in vector.

Comment: @mbq:> that did the trick. I was expecting something else.

Comment: @mbq Very elegant! Cannot upvote more :( I initially thought lines with missing values were to be kept as is.

Answer (score 3):

Would that help?

```
> a <- as.data.frame(matrix(scan("1.txt", what="character", 
                                 na.strings=c("NA",paste("V",1:6,sep=""))), 
                     nc=13, byrow=T))
> class(a[,1])
[1] "factor"
> for (i in 1:ncol(a)) a[,i] <- as.numeric(as.character(a[,i]))
> class(a[,1])
[1] "numeric"
> summary(a)  # should work here
```

The way you import data doesn't matter so much; I think the critical part if to convert value as character then as numeric (this allows to convert levels of a factor to their numerical counterparts).

Comment: you can use data.matrix() for that http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.matrix.html